# i can't get all the URL from my json. this code show only first URL of json

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xovak.com/json_logo.php"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSDictionary *Logos = [[[json valueForKey:@"logos"]objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *img = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (id item in Logos) {
        [img addObject:[Logos objectForKey:@"image_file"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",img);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Wain copy and paste above url in to the browser you will json data

Comment: @iDev, will it always be at that link? How useful will this question be in the future if not...

Comment: yes you are said correct but questioner is beginner of our community he doesn't know the concept of community. @Wain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of getting all imagFile From JSON Response. Please Check it.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xovak.com/json_logo.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;

NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *img = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *listOfURL = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSArray *websiteDetails = (NSArray *) [json objectForKey:@"logos"];

for(int count=0; count<[websiteDetails count]; count++)
{
    NSDictionary *websiteInfo = (NSDictionary *) [websiteDetails objectAtIndex:count];
    NSString *imagefile = (NSString *) [websiteInfo objectForKey:@"image_file"];
    if([imagefile length]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Imagefile URL is: %@",imagefile);
        [img addObject:imagefile];
    }
}

listOfURL = img;


---------// Add This Method in TableView Cell For Row at IndexPath Method//-----------------

// Logic For Downloading Image From URL and Show in TableviewCell
//get a dispatch queue

dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[listOfURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //this will set the image when loading is finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        cell.imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
    });
});
```

Comment: in if([session..]) condition session means what ??

Comment: Its just my single ton class where i add all method for all the Class. My Meaning was only to check string is NULL or Not. Thanks For point out.

Comment: and i want display images from this array in imageview plzz... any suggetion from your side which help for this..

Comment: Please Check my edited Answer For Showing ImagesFrom URL and display it in UITableview.

Comment: To All..if i am wrong at answer than let me know. why downvote on my answer without writing any comments. Its not good way. Grow up man.

Comment: Where you face problem? can you please share with us here.

Comment: it will not display any error but not a single image display in tableview cell

Comment: plz give your  mail id so i send the full code to u

Comment: Thanks For quick Reply :). I am tested my code here and it will display automatically once it will downloaded From URL.I am using Asynchronous downloading for downloading image and display it in UIteblaview cell. Can you please share your code here from UITableView delegate Method "CellForRowAtIndex" ? so that i can guide you perfectly.

Comment: My mail id is: "p9983232747@gmail.com". Thanks

Comment: didnt get clear. imageview in uitableview or separate imageview full screen?

Comment: separate imageview full screen

Comment: Yes you can. you have make scrollview with imageview which display all images in horizontal view.

Comment: same method of tablecell for uiimageview  ? and how to change image one by one using swipe gesture.....

Comment: for adding gesture you have to add UITapGestureRecognizer Method.. For more information you can create you New question where i can answer. Thanks for Reply

Comment: i can ask question for some reason so send code to your mail id

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `Logos` shouldn't be a `NSArray`? At least, that's what it looks like from your JSON object.

Do this instead:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xovak.com/json_logo.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;

NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *Logos = [[json valueForKey:@"logos"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *img = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSDictionary *item in Logos) {
  [img addObject:[item objectForKey:@"image_file"]];
  NSLog(@"%@",img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting only one item in `Logos`. Plus, it should not be `NSMutableDictionary` but an `NSArray`.

On the other hand, the items you're looping on in `Logos` *are* actually `NSDictionary`s.

So, your code should now be:

```
    NSArray *Logos = [json valueForKey:@"logos"];
    NSMutableArray *img = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *item in Logos) {
        [img addObject:[item objectForKey:@"image_file"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",img);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `NSDictionary *Logos = [[[json valueForKey:@"logos"]objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];` with `NSArray *Logos = [[json valueForKey:@"logos"] mutableCopy];` to get all objects.